# LINQ to SQL Classes with INotifyPropertyChanged and IDataErrorInfo for WPF bindings

Tags: wpf, linq, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged, idataerrorinfo

I use the LINQ to SQL Classes to access to my database. Now I want to use the LINQ to SQL Classes for WPF DataBindings and validation. How do I implement these two interfaces to my projects Model? Is it possible implement INotifyProperty automatically?

Answer (score 0):

This gets you the INotifyPropertyChanged part.

[NotifyPropertyWeaver](http://github.com/SimonCropp/NotifyPropertyWeaver)

Then IDataErrorInfo can be done in a base class.